# Java - Returning from a recursive function

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to return all possible permutations of values in a String array. I've come up with the following code making all possible permutations; it works fine.

```
private void combineArray(String sPrefix, String[] sInput, int iLength) {
    if (iLength == sPrefix.length()) {
        //This value should be returned and concatenated:
        System.out.println(sPrefix);
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<sInput.length; i++) {
            combineArray(sPrefix.concat(sInput[i]), ArrayUtils.removeElement(sInput, sInput[i]), iLength);
        }
    }
}
```

If I put in {x, y ,z} it prints to the console:

```
xyz
xzy
yxz
yzx
zxy
zyx
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to return these values to the original calling function. So I'd like this function not to return 'void' but a 'String' containing the concatened values of sPrefix.

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I can't seem to see clearly anymore. :) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not return a list with all the String combinations added? Even better, no?

Comment: Just throwing out ideas, but could you alter an outside array during each iteration, or return an array of values that would return through each recursive level?

Comment: Yeah, just return the data from the recursive routine.  You can return either a regular `[]` array, or one of the collection classes, the latter being better as you can add to it as you return from each level.

Comment: LOL, you're all ridiculously fast. :) Thanks! I initially thought passing in a list parameter wouldn't work because Java only passes by value and not by reference, as far as I know... ? Also, is there no elegant way of using return statements?

Comment: Java passes all objects by reference.  Only "scalers" -- ints, chars, floats, etc -- are passed by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than returning a list, I think it might work better to pass *in* a list as an argument, and populate it inside the method:

```
private void combineArray(List<String> lOut, String sPrefix, String[] sInput, int iLength) {
    if (iLength == sPrefix.length()) {
        //This value should be returned and concatenated:
        System.out.println(sPrefix);
        lOut.add(sPrefix);
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<sInput.length; i++) {
            combineArray(lOut, sPrefix.concat(sInput[i]), ArrayUtils.removeElement(sInput, sInput[i]), iLength);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then have a wrapper method that creates the `new ArrayList<String>`, passes it into the above method, and returns it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `ArrayList<String>` and add all the strings to it.. And then you can return this ArrayList..

```
List<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
private void combineArray(String sPrefix, String[] sInput, int iLength) {
    if (iLength == sPrefix.length()) {
        listString.add(sPrefix);
        //This value should be returned and concatenated:
        System.out.println(sPrefix);
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<sInput.length; i++) {
            combineArray(sPrefix.concat(sInput[i]), ArrayUtils.removeElement(sInput, sInput[i]), iLength);
        }
    }
    return listString;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep appending to the same output.. Like this:

```
private String combineArray(String sPrefix, String[] sInput, int iLength, String output) {
    if (iLength == sPrefix.length()) {
        //This value should be returned and concatenated:
        System.out.println(sPrefix);
        output = output+"|+sPrefix;
        return output;
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<sInput.length; i++) {
            output = combineArray(sPrefix.concat(sInput[i]), ArrayUtils.removeElement(sInput, sInput[i]), iLength, output);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a ListArray instead of a String, once the basic concept works..